# Lists and Tuples

Tags: python, list

Let us consider

```
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

How do I get the required output `z`?

```
z = [('1', 'a') , ('b', '2') , ('c', '3') , ('d', '4') , ('e', '5')]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> x = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] 
>>> y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> z = zip(x, y)
>>> z
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'd'), ('5', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
z = zip(x, y)
```